# Validation Issues on Hidden DropDownListFor's ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, hidden

FINAL EDIT: The problem was that ViewBag.PropName   ==    Model.PropName; 
FIX: ViewBag.PropName ===> ViewBag.PropName2

This is my first time posting; I'm new and think I messed up the layout... so sorry!
I encountered some issues with client-side validation for hidden dropdownlistfor's.
I am working with ASP.NET MVC3 and have a lot of hidden ddl on this page.
The validation however, doesn't work for some ddl's.
Has anyone ever had a problem with this before?

These are 2 properties; 1 working, 1 failing

```
//VALIDATION FAILS
[Required]
[Range(0, 4)]
public int TiresBack { get; set; }

//VALIDATION WORKS
[Required]
[Range(0, 4)]
public int TechnicalState { get; set; }
```

This is a piece the razor:

```
<tr>//THIS DOESN'T WORK
    <td style="width: 38%;">  
        @txtFor("tiresBack")
    </td>
//This is JQuery Star-Rating.
    <td align="center" id="starsTiresBack">
    </td>
    <td>                            
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TiresBack, ViewBag.TiresBack as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { style = "display:none;" })
        <input class="blueButton" type="button" id="btnBrandRearTires" value="@txtFor("brandTiresBack")" />
        <span>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TiresBack)</span> <span>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrandRearTires)</span>
    </td>
</tr>
 //THIS WORKS
<tr>
    <td style="width: 38%;">
        @txtFor("technicalState")                            
    </td>
    <td id="starsTechnicalState" align="center">
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TechnicalState, ViewBag.TechState as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { style = "display:none;" })
        <input class="blueButton" type="button" id="btnTechnicalStateDescription" value="@txtFor("technicalStateDescriptionButton")" style="display:none;"/>
        <span>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TechnicalState)</span> <span>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TechnicalStateDescription)</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

EDIT1: Initialised in the controller using this method:

```
    public static List<SelectListItem> CreateDefaultStateList(int? selected = -1)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> sl = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = -1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem();
            if (i == 0 || i == -1)
                sli.Text = "";
            else
                sli.Text = i.ToString();
            sli.Value = i.ToString();
            if (i == selected)
                sli.Selected = true;
            sl.Add(sli);
        }
        return sl;
    }
```

EDIT2: The create controller. defaultstatelist is what got returned from the method posted above.

```
List<SelectListItem> defaultStateList = CreateDefaultStateList();

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    FillViewBag();
    ViewBag.PropX = defaultStateList;
    ViewBag.TiresFront = defaultStateList;
    ViewBag.TechState = defaultStateList;
    ViewBag.PropY= defaultStateList;
    ViewBag.PropZ= defaultStateList;
    ViewBag.PropA= defaultStateList;
    ViewBag.PropB= defaultStateList;
    ViewBag.PropC= defaultStateList;
    ViewBag.PropD= defaultStateList;  

    return View(); 
}
```

Typing this I notice the the default value in the method. That could be it...
==> Tried it, wasn't it. Updated code to '-1' as default value now.

Comment: How these properties are initialized in the controller?

Comment: @Andrei The list coming from the edited code is put in the viewbag

Comment: Could you please show all the code of the controller? Not any a single method, bu the actual assignment of the ViewBag properties? I suspect that these dropdowns have different initial state - the first one has an empty value selected, and the second one has some nonempty value selected. Thus the difference in their behavior. But to confirm that the actual controller code is needed.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I edited the article

Comment: Now its clear that the problem is definitely not in default values. Another possible cause might be values assigned to the corresponding model properties. For instance, if `Model.TiresBack` is set to 0, and `Model.TechState` is set to say 3, the code above would behave exactly as you describe - the second drop down will pass the validation while the first won't.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean.
Also note that it is impossible to select 0 (but it is needs to be there for other parts of the app)
So it comes in with -1 selected and using JQuery stars you can only select 1-4. So if there was no selection, the value should still be -1.

Comment: Most likely you are return from controller something like `return View("ViewName", model)`. The part of the `model` object's class you have shown in the first piece of code. Now if this `model` has some not-default value stored in property `TechnicalState`, it will affect the state of second drop down list, and it will pass the validation. To make the long story short - could you add construction of this `model` object to the post?

Comment: I use return View(); (Bad copy-paster)
Nothing more. All of the lists are the same and all of the props have the same datatype (int).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `ViewBag.PropName == Model.PropName;` 
FIX:  Rename `ViewBag.PropName` to something else like `ViewBag.PropName2`.